# Simpletransformers not using all data to train and evaluate?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, simpletransformers

so I am using simpletransformers on my classification task, I have 2 columns in my Dataframe (sentence, label) of size 3890

When I train the model it shows that it is only using 8 samples from my training data? why is that why isn't it 3890/3890. (see red bar 0% in the image below)

[image]

Also in the evaluation its showing 0% (my test is 1945 rows), although the len of output is 1945

[image]

This is the rest of my code:
# install simpletransformers
!pip install simpletransformers

```
# check installed version
!pip freeze | grep simpletransformers

from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel

# define hyperparameter
train_args ={#"reprocess_input_data": True,
             "overwrite_output_dir": True,
             "fp16":False,
             "num_train_epochs": 2} 

# Create a ClassificationModel
model = ClassificationModel(
    "bert", "bert-base-cased",
    args=train_args
)
```